# How to create an object using JACOB

Tags: java, jacob

I managed to load two dll's

```
    System.load("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EXAMPLE Client\\Bin\\EXAMPLE.Client.SDK.dll");
    System.load("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EXAMPLE Client\\Bin\\EXAMPLE.Common.SDK.dll");
```

Next step is to create on object calls `SDKModel`. How do I do this? I tried:

`ActiveXComponent example = new ActiveXComponent("EXAMPLE.Common.SDK.SDKModel");`

But then I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't get object clsid from progid
```

I'm unsure whether I'm on the right track. How would create the object `SDKModel`?

Answer (score 1):

Its because you didn't registered your dll in system. Check path of `cd` in both code

To register follow [important: Be careful using **regasm.exe** as it different file than unregister]

```
c:
cd\
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 
RegAsm /verbose /nologo /codebase D:\path_to_dll\mydll.dll
```

To unregister follow

```
c:
cd\
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
RegAsm.exe /unregister D:\path_to_dll\mydll.dll
```

---

**Update:**

To register / Unregister use `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` framework..