# Can't figure out how to register dll to avoid "Can't get object clsid from progid"

Tags: java, autoit, jacob

I am trying to use autoit with java, and have installed AHK and the jacob bridge to autoitx4java.AutoItx. I have the jacob dll (jacob-1.18-86x.dll) stored in windows/syswow64 . When I try to compile the program (imports are `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; import java.util.Date; import autoitx4java.AutoItX;)`, I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jacob.com.ComFailException: Can't get object clsid from progid
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.createInstanceNative(Native Method)
at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.<init>(Dispatch.java:99)
at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.<init>(ActiveXComponent.java:58)
at autoitx4java.AutoItX.<init>(AutoItX.java:181)
at MainTest.login(MainTest.java:126)
at MainTest.setadmin(MainTest.java:181)
at MainTest.runbasic(MainTest.java:21)
at MainTest.main(MainTest.java:15)
```

After searching, I thought it might be that the dll wasn't registered, such as at  [How to create an object using JACOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144511/how-to-create-an-object-using-jacob) , but that didn't work. After typing the registering command from there, I get a "RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load 'c:\windows\syswow64\jacob-1.18-x86.dll' because it is not a vaild .NET assembly. Also tried "regsvr32 jacob-1.18-x86.dll" from another way to register outside of the answer above, but that got me a "The module "jacob-1.18-x86.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "jacob-1.18-x86.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and try again. Any ideas?

Edit: Someone suggested this was for AutoIt and not autohotkey. This is corrected in the question and the tags. Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure this is for Autohotkey and not for autoit?

Comment: And check this for your error: http://www.javaquery.com/2013/12/comjacobcomcomfailexception-cant-get.html

Comment: My company blocks the OLE viewer page for the download. What is it trying to get at?

Comment: Also, is AutoItX an activeX component?

Comment: Do you know which OLE object I'm looking for? The link you provided just tells you to look for them, not what to look for or what to do if it's missing.

Answer (score 3):

By just registering only AutoITX3 DLL, issue has been resolved.
For Win32: AutoItX3.dll and Win64: AutoItX3_x64.dll

Register using command: **regsvr32 AbsolutePathOfRequiredDLLFile**

Comment: It works for me. I needed to run this command as administrator. Thank you.